# Android rest webservice problem

Tags: android

```
package com.rest;
import java.io.IOException;  

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.util.Log;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.EditText;  
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;  
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;  
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;  
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;  
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;  
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;  
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class rest extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    String URL = "http://sc2.mystreamserver.com:8050/admin.cgi?mode=viewxml";  
       String result = "";  
        String deviceId = "xxxxx" ;  
       final String tag = "Your Logcat tag: ";  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);




          /** Called when the activity is first created. */  

        callWebService();  

                final EditText txtSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);  
             txtSearch.setOnClickListener(new EditText.OnClickListener(){  
                public void onClick(View v){txtSearch.setText("");}  
             });  

               final Button btnSearch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);  
                btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){  
                    public void onClick(View v) {  
                        String query = txtSearch.getText().toString();  


                   }  
               });  

          } // end onCreate()  

           public void callWebService(){  
              HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
               HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);  
               request.addHeader("username","    "); 
               request.addHeader("pass","   ");  
               ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();  
               try {  
                  result = httpclient.execute(request, handler);  
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
                    result=e.toString(); 
                } catch (IOException e) {  
                    result=e.toString();  
                }  
                httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();  
               Log.i(tag, result);  
               Toast.makeText(rest.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } // end callWebService()  

 }
```

i am not getting the result.plz help to get result....

Comment: Poor question is poor. Make an effort in editing your question and explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
public void callWebService()
{  
    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("Your Url");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username","your user name");
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password","your password");
    postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpResponse response = hc.execute(postMethod);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if (entity != null) 
    {
            InputStream inStream = entity.getContent();
            result= Utility.convertStreamToString(inStream);
            Log.i("---------------- Result",result);
    }
} // end callWebService()
```

---

```
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
{
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   String line = null;
   try 
   {
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
       {
           sb.append(line + "\n");
       }
   } 
   catch (IOException e) 
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } 
   finally 
   {
       try 
       {
           is.close();
       } 
       catch (IOException e) 
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   return sb.toString();
```

}

Comment: If I wanted to send a large file (maybe 1mb) instead of string content how would one do that? Would the convertStreamToString need to be different or split up? What would be in place of Stringbuilder?